# Filter design for piezoelectric transducer

Tags: filter, piezo

I'd like to use a piezoelectric transducer at one of its resonant frequency (4500 Hz). In order to get a clearer signal, I would like to use a band-pass filter.

First of all I calculated the impedance of the piezoelectric transducer. To achieve that, I put a variable resistor at the output of the transducer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXMikN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then I generated an audio signal with a frequency of 4500 Hz, and measured for two different values of Ri the amplitude of the voltage `V` across the variable resistance.

For both values, I used the formula`Ri/(Ri+Z)=V/V1`, which allowed me to calculate Z (I found 12 kOhms). Is the method correct?

Now my problem is: I'd like to apply a band-pass filter, with a centre frequency of 4500 Hz, and a band-width of a few hundreds Hz. But according to the formulas I've found for RLC band-pass filters, it seems that I will need an inductance definitely too big to reach such a BW. What would be the best way to implement the band pass filter, preferably with passive components? Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a sensor (probably) or an emitter in which a BPF isn't necessary. What Q do you want ? 100 is possible with a pot. and 2 Op Amps or less with 1

Comment: I'd like a bandwidth of a few hundred Hz. Also I'd prefer to use passive components, as I need to minimize the energy consumption.

Comment: how many micro amps is acceptible

Comment: If your piezo has a decent resonance @ 4500 Hz, you may not need a band-pass filter. Some piezos are so high-Q that you may have to work hard to de-Q it. Do you need extra filtering to knock down adjacent interfering signals & noise?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 A few uA would be a maximum.

Comment: @glen_geek That's true, but I would like to eliminate other frequencies as far as possible. The piezo is supposed to detect the resonant frequency and trigger an interrupt to an MCU, so I want to prevent false triggering.

Comment: @Vincz777 - OK, then extra bandpass RC op-amp filter as TonyStewart has advised. You'll have to follow this with an envelope-detector and comparator to generate your interrupt. Even so, some extra software to eliminate false triggers.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks again! Sorry to bother again but I'm obsessed with the voltage offset of the op-amp, which equals more or less the amplitude of the piezo signal (3 mV). Does the circuit given by Tony Stewart works with such a low signal?

Comment: @Vincz777 Yes, should be OK - the op-amp may add some DC offset to its output, but any offset can be easily blocked by a coupling capacitor to the next stage - your envelope detector that generates the interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would use this basic circuit with rail to rail Op Amp single supply but move all the grounds to Vbat/2 with split R's ,
  [image]
- then use a trimpot for the output divider to change Q
- Q = f/BW. you indicate few hundred Hz or a Q=15

  - then choose input R > 15k to 100k
  - easy formula exist for this active BPF.
  - Choose a low noise [Op Amp with low current .](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/2556125?k=&pkeyword=&pv41=135&pv41=112&FV=fff40027%2Cfff800dd&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)
  - wide range of supply voltage options are available

any questions?

Yes LC BPF will need large inductors, not feasible or accurate due to large tolerances.

If you want wide bandwidth but steeper out of band rejection and high sensitivity, you can use two stages cascaded with any gain that you want.
This **[site](http://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/Butterworth_Bandpass_active.php)** has an auto-design input.
[image]
1% values can be selected to the nearest part or changed on the linked site.  But again for a single supply, dc gnd must be changed to Vbat/2.

Comment: Thanks! But how should I choose the Op-Amp? The voltage amplitude of the resonant frequency across the piezo is only 2-3 mV. In the link you provided, I didn't find any op-amp with large GBW, low voltage offset (but is it necessary?), and low power consumption.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP6144-E-ST/MCP6144-E-ST-ND/1098552 These 4 IC's use much< 1uA... What will excite this resonator so precisely?

Comment: Thanks! Is the +/3 mV voltage offset of MCP6141 a problem, as my signal is only 2-3 mV wide? The resonator will simply be excited by an audio soundwave. Then I'd like to plug a comparator to the output of the filter, and the comparator will trigger an interrupt to an MCU.

Comment: You would be wise to use a diode peak integrator with hysteresis like  a Schmitt trigger gate.  A very loud bang can still contain spectrum in all frequencies. Use the extra OpAmp as a comparator with sufficient positive feedback >10% and BPF's reject DC. Choose gain wisely. With this design, you can choose any frequency and use an electret mic instead.

Comment: Not sure of what you mean by diode peak integrator. The comparator I use (MCP6541) has already a 3 mV hysteresis. I discarded using electret mic because of the energy consumption.

Comment: Then you would be wiser to choose a narrower bandwidth or higher Q which has the LPF effect and use >20% hysteresis. If you don't rectify then you will get interupts on each cycle

Comment: What do you mean by ">20% hysteresis"? 20% of what? The output of the comparator will generate an interrupt to wake-up the MCU, so I thought it was okay if multiple interrupt where risen. Then I planned to apply a low-pass filter at the output of the comparator to acquire the signal from an ADC pin of the MCU (signal will be OOK encoded).